# Pulling data from a PostgreSQL table and rendering to a web page using Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, postgresql

I am unable to pull data from a newly populated PostgreSQL table and render it on a web page in my Django application. I have a small application where a user uploads a .json file. The app performs some operations on the json, resulting in a Pandas dataframe. This dataframe then populates a PostgreSQL data table, resulting in one column of data whose length corresponds to the initial data operations. So far, this works correctly.

I have checked the postgres database to verify that the table has been populated, and it has. However, I'm having trouble pulling that column of data from the database and displaying it on the same page that the user uploaded the data from. I'm unsure why I can't easily retrieve the data from the database, loop over it, and render it to the page. The error message tells me that my app "id" does not exist, despite including an "id" primary key in my models.py.

As you can see, in my views.py file, I have a ProcessedDataListView class that is intended to create the context and send data to my data_display.html file. Here is my error message:

> In template
> /home/linux/django_app/eef/myapp/templates/upload_json.html, error at
> line 12
>
> column myapp_processeddatamodel.id does not exist LINE 1: SELECT
> "myapp_processeddatamodel"."id", "myapp_processeddata... ^

PostgreSQL log

```
2023-03-18 11:15:19.782 GMT [9694] linux@mydbx STATEMENT:  SELECT "myapp_processeddatamodel"."id", "myapp_processeddatamodel"."my_list" FROM "myapp_processeddatamodel" LIMIT 21
2023-03-18 11:15:19.782 GMT [9694] linux@mydbx ERROR:  column myapp_processeddatamodel.id does not exist at character 8
2023-03-18 11:15:19.782 GMT [9694] linux@mydbx STATEMENT:  SELECT "myapp_processeddatamodel"."id", "myapp_processeddatamodel"."my_list" FROM "myapp_processeddatamodel" LIMIT 21
2023-03-18 11:15:19.782 GMT [9694] linux@mydbx ERROR:  column myapp_processeddatamodel.id does not exist at character 8
2023-03-18 11:15:19.782 GMT [9694] linux@mydbx STATEMENT:  SELECT "myapp_processeddatamodel"."id", "myapp_processeddatamodel"."my_list" FROM "myapp_processeddatamodel" LIMIT 21
2023-03-18 11:15:19.782 GMT [9694] linux@mydbx ERROR:  column myapp_processeddatamodel.id does not exist at character 8
2023-03-18 11:15:19.782 GMT [9694] linux@mydbx STATEMENT:  SELECT "myapp_processeddatamodel"."id", "myapp_processeddatamodel"."my_list" FROM "myapp_processeddatamodel" LIMIT 21
2023-03-18 11:15:19.783 GMT [9694] linux@mydbx ERROR:  column myapp_processeddatamodel.id does not exist at character 8
2023-03-18 11:15:19.783 GMT [9694] linux@mydbx STATEMENT:  SELECT "myapp_processeddatamodel"."id", "myapp_processeddatamodel"."my_list" FROM "myapp_processeddatamodel" LIMIT 21
```

Database structure

```py
from django.db import models


class AuthGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=150)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'auth_group'


class AuthGroupPermissions(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    group = models.ForeignKey(AuthGroup, models.DO_NOTHING)
    permission = models.ForeignKey('AuthPermission', models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'auth_group_permissions'
        unique_together = (('group', 'permission'),)


class AuthPermission(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey('DjangoContentType', models.DO_NOTHING)
    codename = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'auth_permission'
        unique_together = (('content_type', 'codename'),)


class AuthUser(models.Model):
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField()
    username = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=150)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField()
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'auth_user'


class AuthUserGroups(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(AuthUser, models.DO_NOTHING)
    group = models.ForeignKey(AuthGroup, models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'auth_user_groups'
        unique_together = (('user', 'group'),)


class AuthUserUserPermissions(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(AuthUser, models.DO_NOTHING)
    permission = models.ForeignKey(AuthPermission, models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'auth_user_user_permissions'
        unique_together = (('user', 'permission'),)


class DjangoAdminLog(models.Model):
    action_time = models.DateTimeField()
    object_id = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    object_repr = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    action_flag = models.SmallIntegerField()
    change_message = models.TextField()
    content_type = models.ForeignKey('DjangoContentType', models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(AuthUser, models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'django_admin_log'


class DjangoContentType(models.Model):
    app_label = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'django_content_type'
        unique_together = (('app_label', 'model'),)


class DjangoMigrations(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    app = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    applied = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'django_migrations'


class DjangoSession(models.Model):
    session_key = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=40)
    session_data = models.TextField()
    expire_date = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'django_session'


class MyappProcesseddatamodel(models.Model):
    number_0 = models.TextField(db_column='0', blank=True, null=True)  # Field renamed because it wasn't a valid Python identifier.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'myapp_processeddatamodel'
```

Views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import JsonFileUploadForm
from .models import ProcessedDataModel
from django.db import models
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import ProcessedDataModel

import json

publication_type_output = [{
    5215227: 'Journal article',
    5215228: 'Dissertation or thesis',
    5215229: 'Technical report',
    5215230: 'Book or book chapter',
    5215231: 'Conference paper'
}]

def upload_json(request):
    # Clear the database before processing new data
    # clear_database()
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'upload_button' in request.POST:
        form = JsonFileUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            # load the file data from the TemporaryUploadedFile object
            data = json.load(request.FILES['json_file'])

            processed_data = get_data(data, publication_type_output)

            # Replace these values with your actual PostgreSQL credentials
            db_url = 'postgresql://linux:mypass@localhost/mydbx'

            # Create an SQLAlchemy engine
            engine = create_engine(db_url)

            # Replace 'your_table_name' with the actual table name you want to use
            processed_data.to_sql('myapp_processeddatamodel', engine, if_exists='replace', index=False)

            # Fetch all rows from the table
            all_data = ProcessedDataModel.objects.all()
            context = {'form': form, 'data': all_data}
            return render(request, 'upload_json.html', context)

    else:
        form = JsonFileUploadForm()

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'upload_json.html', context)

def processed_data_view(request):
    processed_data = ProcessedDataModel.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'processed_data.html', {'processed_data': processed_data})

# GET DATA FROM DATABASE AND PASS IT TO A TEMPLATE CONTEXT
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .models import ProcessedDataModel

class ProcessedDataListView(ListView):
    model = ProcessedDataModel
    template_name = 'upload_json.html'
    context_object_name = 'data'
```

app level urls.py

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from .views import ProcessedDataListView

app_name = 'myapp'
urlpatterns = [
    path('upload-json/', views.upload_json, name='upload_json'),
    path('processed-data/', views.processed_data_view, name='processed_data_view'),
    path('upload-json/', views.ProcessedDataListView.as_view(), name='upload-json'),
]
```

models.py

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField

class ProcessedDataModel(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    my_list = models.TextField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.my_list
```

upload_json.html

```html
{% block content %}
  <h1>Upload JSON File</h1>
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
      {{ form.json_file.label_tag }}
      {{ form.json_file }}
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="upload_button" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
  </form>

  {% if data %}
  <h2>Data:</h2>
  <ul>
    {% for item in data %}
      <li>{{ item.my_list }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

I have already tried removing the old PostgreSQL table and database and starting them afresh, though this resulted in the same problem.

Comment: The database error says that column doesn't exist so your code isn't relevant. Show the database structure and a fragment from the PostgreSQL logs. Either it really isn't there or your code is looking in the wrong database or wrong schema or some such.

Comment: Thank you. I have edited the post to include the database structure and a fragment of the PostgreSQL logs.

Comment: Hello. I've solved the problem and no longer require a response. Would it be better for me to delete the question or to answer my own question with a proper response?

Comment: I always think it's useful to have an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering myself as I have now found the problem and the solution.

I had a PostGres table setup with a colunm named "x", ready to be populated. I was attempting to populate this column with a Pandas dataframe, though I was mistakenly not specifying a column name (which should have been "x"). For this reason it was being assigned the name 0, which of course did not match "x". This meant that there was no information for me to pull out of "x" to display on the page, hence why there was no display. I now pass in a dataframe with the same column name as that of my corresponding database column name, and the data is populated and displayed on the page with no problems.